# Break 1 api into multiple by Dell Boomi?

Tags: api, etl, middleware, boomi

I am trying to call a system which does not have it's api bulkified. So  basically I have 1 record and for example 1000 child records.  In order to send this info to other system am currently required to make 1000 api calls. Can we use middleware Dell Boomi to do this for me.

In short, I call only one Dell Boomi api with all 1000 records and Dell Boomi breaks into 1000 such calls and send this to other system.

Is this scenario even possible? Any suggestion in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried 'Split Documents' under data process component ?

Answer (score 2):

user2272821 makes the assumption that you already have Boomi...

A Dell Boomi process (program) treats your workflow like a flowchart.

The first step would read your parent record (or params) from a source (like a file)
The second step would use a connection object to access your 1000 records
The third step would be to Data Process Shape to split your 'document' into 1000 bits.
The next step would be to process each 'bit' in some way - or many ways... 
(There is built in functionality to handle REST and SOAP calls.)

so, yes, it should be able to help you.

note that once you have Boomi, you'll find that you can add filtering and divert records with different values down different paths, send rejected records to a log, all sorts of cool stuff.